# Percentages in SSRS Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

**EDIT:** The chart is fixed when I use a stacked chart instead of a stacked *percentage* chart, but this still doesn't tell me what is wrong with using the percentage chart.

I have a stacked percentage chart which is going from 0 to 10000% instead of 0 to 100%. It appears as if the values are formatted correctly (they add up to 1.01 due to rounding), and even dividing all the values by 100 in the query does not change it.

This is how the chart renders:

[image: c]

with the following Vertical Axis Properties:

[image: vap]

I have a table below (with identical number formatting but with 2 percentage points), however that displays as expected:

[image]

Finally, here is the raw data set with an additional sum column not reflected in SSRS:

[image]

Has anyone come across this issue before? If I manually set the range of the chart from 0-100% (0-1) I can only see that bottom blue series.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yep. I've seen exactly this. The numbers that the percent chart axis generates are in the range 0 to 100. But when you apply the number formatting as a percent, then the numbers are multiplied by 100 for display.

The trick to fix/work around this is to set the display format to only add the percent sign, not really format the number as a percent. Happily, this requires just one character:

1. In the Number format for the axis, switch the Category to "Custom." If you just switched from Percentage, you will see something similar to `0%`.
2. Insert a backslash before the percent symbol: `0\%` to indicate that you need a literal percent symbol, not to format the number as a percent (multiplied by 100.)

Voila.

Comment: Man, this saved my life today. Thanks!