# Percentages in SSRS - Exporting to excel

Tags: excel, matrix, reporting-services, percentage

According to  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874197/percentages-in-ssrs-chart) I need to put my custom number format like this in order to see a % symbol

```
#,0\%
```

The output looks fine in browsers (lets say, I see 12% which is correct) the problem is when I export the report to excel, I see this:

```
1.200\%
```

How can I see 12% in both places?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the slash, and use only "#,0%", that will work.

This will turn the value ".12" into "12%".

If you want to add a space between "12" and "%" use "#,0 %".

If you want to include 2 decimal points, use "#,0.00%" (which will get you "12.00%").

Comment: Ah I see. I would recommend dividing the value by 100.00 in your dataset or (if the value "12" is used in other calculations in your dataset) in the cell in which the value is displayed. I'm not sure why the "\" is behaving like that in the Excel export, but this would solve your problem.