# 10000% on srrs chart

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I'm creating a report in SSRS and on two of my 100% stacked bar charts have encountered some errors. When I change the number format to percentage instead of the values adding up to 100% they add up to 10000%.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Percentages in SSRS Chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874197/percentages-in-ssrs-chart)

Comment: This was happened if you considers the multiplication of 100 in expression  (e.g a*100/b ) and format is set to percentage. So to get the proper result, either you remove percentage from format or remove *100 from expression.